# What is the Available Field Types in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

i' working With SharePoint server 2013 and i'm using Visual Studio 2013 in order to create and defining **Custom Columns**, i noticed that in VS there are no suggestions when we want to set the Field Type.

i searched on Google but i didn't find any complete list.

is there a list contain all this type ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint 2013 supports nearly the same Field Types like SharePoint 2010. I found the following list for the supported Field Types in SharePoint 2010:

http://koenvosters.wordpress.com/2010/04/27/available-field-types-in-sharepoint-2010/

On Technet i found a list of the supported Field Types of SharePoint 2013:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa979575(v=office.15).aspx
(Scroll down to the category **Type**)

Only the specific Field Types for Taxonomy and so one are missing in this list. I only Know from one NEW Field Type in SharePoint 2013. And this is the Geolocation Field. More Informationen about this Field and the functionality you will find [here](http://msscorner.de/2013/01/21/the-new-powerful-geolocation-field-in-sharepoint-2013/).

```
<Field Type='Geolocation' DisplayName='Geolocation' />
```

I hope i could help you. Otherwise let me know it:)

Answer (score 0):

For programmatically check available field types, please refer to collection

**FieldTypeDefinitionCollection** of **SPWeb**
Each item of which contains **Type** property and other field definition information